# How to setup vhosts for local development

Tags: apache, vhosts

How can I set up Apache 2.2 to load the site from htdocs/example/ when I write in the address bar example.local?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that example.local resolves to your local machine, easiest way is by adding a line like

```
127.0.0.1  example.local
```

to your hosts file (linux: /etc/hosts; win: %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts).
And than you need a vhost in your apache config, like (this is **very** basic)

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ServerName    example.local
  DocumentRoot  /path/to/htdocs
  ErrorLog      /path/to/error.log
  CustomLog     /path/to/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

That way you should be able to to access files in htdocs/example/ via http://example.local/example/

For more details please refer to the [fine apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org)

Comment: What if I want to add multiple websites, example1.local,example2.local etc?